# Can WinXP screensavers be used in Win7

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

Two part question:

Can WinXP screensavers be used in Win7?

Where can I find a copy of WinXP's Windows logon screensaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least some WinXP screensavers work in Windows 7 (see [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/scrolling-marquee-screen-saver/18a37078-f659-49d0-b80f-68449240d1fd)).

I would think that you would be best advised to copy the WinXP Windows logon screensaver (which I think is logon.scr) from a Windows XP machine, if you have one lying around, and then try it out.

Edited to add: in fact, someone has written a [howto](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7226-windows-logo-screen-saver-restore.html) guide, so presumably it works -- although I wouldn't necessarily put too much faith in the download provided.